# PHP, XML - trouble understanding how to access attributes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have been working on a small project involving PHP and XML,
the difficulty I am having comes from accessing attributes in a node.

Here is an example of accessing an attribute from a node:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<a>
<foo name="one" game="lonely">1</foo>
</a>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

foreach ($xml->foo[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
?>
```

In the above code, I cannot seem to understand the `foo[0]` bit.
For example, I am troubled over why you have to do `foo[0]->att...`
instead of just `foo->att...`.

Thank you for your time,
- Michael Mitchell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `$xml->foo` allows to iterate over all `<foo>` child elements of the node in `$xml`. This can be zero or more child nodes:

```
foreach ($xml->foo as $foo)
{
    echo "<foo>\n";
    foreach ($foo->attributes() as $name => $value) {
        echo "$name=\"$value\"\n";
    }
}
```

Therefore if you need only one specific of all these zero or more elements, you need to specify which one you mean. That can be done by adding the array braces and it's zero-based position, here `$xml->foo[0]`:

```
$foo = $xml->foo[0];
echo "<foo>\n";
foreach ($foo->attributes() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name=\"$value\"\n";
}
```

Comment: So, by using foo[0] you are specifying the first of the `foo` nodes. Thanks

Comment: Yes, but I've actually just double checked and my answer is not really correct/complete. In your example you can use `$xml->foo` for the first element, too. As that is the one, it does the job for you already, however if there are more elements, you need to specify that: http://codepad.org/1OWxsDxU

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple foo elements. You are getting the first of them.